# XPATH : text()='BUY NOW' is working but not contains(text(),'BUY NOW')

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

In Flipkart page, I searched for Apple ipads and clicked on first search result. Here, I wanted to click on 'BUY NOW'.

Typical page looks like this:

[image: Typical Facebook Apple iPad page]

I used the following xpath and it worked:

```
//button[text()='BUY NOW']
```

Then I used the xpath with 'contains' but it didn't work:

```
//button[contains(text(),'BUY NOW')]
```

Also this:

```
//button[contains(text(),'BUY')]
```

But none worked. I really surprised as to why 'contains' is not identifying the elements. I found the same behavior with 'Add to Cart' button as well.

Then I tried to identify another element - 'Wi-Fi+4G' with contains and it worked:

```
//a[contains(text(),'Wi-Fi+4G')]
//a[text()='Wi-Fi+4G']
```

Both the above xpath worked for me.

> So, can anyone please explain why 'contains' is not working here?

Comment: Can you share html of the elements?

Comment: `<button class="_2AkmmA _2Npkh4 _2kuvG8 _7UHT_c" type="button"><span class="_279WdV"></span> <!-- -->BUY NOW</button>`. This is the html of the button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is an interesting question.

**Let me share my findings.** First of all `//button[contains(text(),'BUY NOW')]` doesn't really look up the element in Chrome dev tools. But `//button[contains(.,'BUY NOW')]` does the trick.

**Check this thing:**

[image]

This is comment element.

If to copypaste form to [this site](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) and try to apply this xpath, it will show up the following error

> Unable to perform XPath operation. A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of contains() ("", "BUY NOW")

So let's check what `text()` function returns for the element, having noticed that `//button[contains(.,'BUY NOW')]` works, lets try to process the following: `//button[contains(.,'BUY NOW')]/text()`. It turns out that `text()` returns two `text` elements which is not the correct input for `contains()` function.

Unlike this button, [Wi-Fi+4G] does not have such the property (`text()` function will return the only single element for that). This is why contains works perfectly for that button.

**Summing up** (mostly from [this discussion on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493732/difference-between-text-and-string)):

- `text()` function returns all the text nodes under the specified element. Comment tag breaks inner text into several nodes
- There is a function that ignores the node structure but just converts inner text nodes into a single string, It is called `string()`
- You can omit using `string()` function when use `contains()` but just use `contains(., 'your text')` since `.` is automatically taken as `string(.)`

Answer (score 1):

In XPath 1.0, `contains(NS, 'string')` where NS is a node-set tests whether the first node in NS contains the supplied string. In your case, `text()` is selecting several text nodes (one before the comment and one after), and only the first is considered.

This is why we advise against using `text()` except in very special circumstances. It's nearly always better to use `.`, for example `//button[contains(., 'label')]`. This will return true if any of the text nodes contains `'label'`, or even if the string is split across several text nodes.

The rule for '=' is different: `NS = 'string'` returns true if ANY node in the node-set is equal to the supplied string.

In XPath 2.0, `contains()` and similar functions throw an error if you supply a node-set containing multiple nodes.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use this 
xpath: .//button[contains(.,'BUY NOW')]
CSS path: form>button